# What does it basically mean with scope annotations in two components (one depends on the other)

Tags: android, dagger-2

In my Android project, I have two project modules, an `main` module and a `core` module.

In main module, I have a dagger component, `MainComponent`:

```
 // it has dependency on CoreComponent
@Component(modules = [MyModule::class], dependencies = [CoreComponent::class])
@FeatureScope
interface MainComponent {
    fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)
}
```

As you can see above, `MainComponent` has a dependency on `CoreComponent`. It also has a custom scope annotation `@FeatureScope`.

In `core` module I have another dagger component called `CoreComponent`:

```
@Component(modules = [CoreModule::class])
@Singleton
interface CoreComponent {
    fun getExpensiveObject(): ExpensiveObject
}

@Module
class CoreModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideExpObj(): ExpensiveObject = ExpensiveObject()
}
```

The `CoreComponent` is annotated by Dagger defined `@Singleton` scope.

I build the Main component in `onCreate()` of `Application` class:

```
class MyApplication : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
          //build main component along with core component
         mainComponent = DaggerMainComponent
                .builder()
                .myModule(MyModule())
                .coreComponent(DaggerCoreComponent.builder().build())
                .build()
     }
}
```

`CoreComponent` & its providers are annotated by `@Singleton`, while `MainComponent` & its providers are annotated by custom annotation `@FeatureScope`.

**Question one:** From lifetime perspective, does the code mean the lifetime of objects in `MainComponent` is shorter than that in `CoreComponent` due to the scope annotations (`@Singleton` in CoreComponent and `@FeatureScope` in MainComponent)?

**Question two:** Since the components are built in `Application` class `onCreate()` which is the entry point of app at runtime, am I right that even though components in two project modules are annotated by different scope annotation, their objects basically have the same lifetime as the whole app's  at runtime?

(I ask those questions because my understanding is that the Dagger defined `@Singleton` scope has the longest lifetime, but I get confused by that with my project)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the fact that `CoreComponent` is annotated with `@Singleton` and the component instance is created in the `Application` means that there will be a single `ExpensiveObject` created in the lifetime of the application.

Concerning the custom annotation (`@FeatureScope`)

> The component implementation ensures that there is only one provision of each scoped binding per instance of the component. 
>   [ref](https://dagger.dev/api/latest/dagger/Component.html)

But since, the `MainComponent` is created only once per application, this custom annotation is effectively the same as the `Singleton` annotation.

If you want a feature-scoped object then you should remove it from the `MainComponent` and have this annotation only on a sub-component. Read the dagger tutorial, and in particular the [step 13](https://dagger.dev/tutorial/13-max-withdrawal-across-commands).

> Annotating both `WithdrawalLimiter` and `UserCommandsRouter` with
>   @PerSession indicates to Dagger that a single `WithdrawalLimiter` should
>   be created for every instance of `UserCommandsRouter`.
>
> ```
> @PerSession
> final class WithdrawalLimiter { ... }
>
> @PerSession
> @Subcomponent(...)
> interface UserCommandsRouter { ... }
> ```